# How to get the type of this Object?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pickle

you can see the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/SerDeUtil.scala#L152) here

```
 val obj = unpickle.loads(row)
```

now that I know `obj` is an ArrayList which is unserialized. I want to know the element in it.

```
 val temp = obj.asInstanceOf[JArrayList[String]]
 for (i <- 0 to temp.size() - 1) {
     print(temp.get(i).getClass)
 }
```

But it print `Object` for every element.So I guess maybe I should use something like `ObjectInputStream` to get the data in every element.

Thank you for any Advice.

Comment: finally I print the data in the nearby code road.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList stores a list of Object references.

At runtime, you can only check instanceof for every element in the ArrayList.

You can check it something like that:

```
for (Object o : list) {
  if (o instanceof YourClass1) {
    //doThing1
  }
  else if (o instanceof YourClass2)) {
    //doThing2
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know the candidate class.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "I want to know the element in it."?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I think the element should contains data